# Excel: Multiple mins in one column

Tags: excel, range, min

I would like to calculate minimum (or maximum, or...) of values in column C, based on condition of specified range in column A and column B, and write it to a cell in column D.

I am trying to combine min, if and range C:C, but it search whole column C, not only part specified by A and B (the same content in A or B).

[Img: "desired result" is in column C](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7j9d6.png)

Comment: Sorry, the column D in image contents numbers 3, only.

Comment: I just see a bunch of data in cells. I don't see "Conditions" in A or B. I have no idea how these values are to be applied to column "C". Is the column "D" values in that picture your "Desired results" or your failed attempt? Please help us understand what you are trying to do here.

Comment: JNevill, thanks for reply. In column D are "desired results" - minimum of values in range C1:C24 (it should be "3", excuse me, I posted incorrect image). Value in C is the number of same values in column A (7 in C7 is the number of values in A1:A7, 3 in C10 is range A8:A10...). These results will change after new value in column B (cell B25).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gather you don't have Office 365 with the newer MINIFS function so here is a pseudo-MINIFS.

```
=AGGREGATE(15, 7, C$1:INDEX(C:C, MATCH(1E+99, C:C))/(C$1:INDEX(C:C, MATCH(1E+99, C:C))<>TEXT(,)), 1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Jeeped, ...I am sorry I posted incorrect image (I failed to edit it) - in D1:D20 should be the 3.

Comment: I had three conditions; I removed two of them.

Comment: Thanks, but so far it doesn´t work, without any error message, so nevermind why. Is your expression accepted in Excel 2016?

Comment: It works, but result is not changing after change in column B - I have edited original photo. Thanks

Comment: put back the column b condition.

Comment: Thank you very much, Jeeped. It Works well in O.365. Can you explain the expression (why did you choose the MATCH as a row_num for index; how do you use / and * ), please? Thanks+

Comment: Jeeped, excuse me, is it possible to send you a file to check? After I applied it to original table, the results are incorrect. Thank you.